# Use Form.Show() but Not running code After Form.Show() Like ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't use Form.ShowDialog() I want use Form.Show() but I want execute code after From.Show() after Form.Closed

```
public void Tools(){
    var frm=new ToolFrm();
    frm.Show();

    //do something
}
```

I want return true and hold execution while the form `frm` is open.

Comment: You mean to halt execution of further lines until your `frm` is open and  go to `return true` only when `frm` get closed

Comment: @sunil Yes Sunil

Comment: Why can't you use ShowDialog() ? Does ToolFrm inherit System.Windows.Forms?

Comment: @D.Foley i user reflection to load toolfrm and toolfrm use external app i want till toolfrm is open app do nothing and when tool frm closed run code after frm.Show(); and Tools Class call from another windows form

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run some code when a modeless form is closed, then you can subscribe to to the form's `FormClosed` event:

```
public bool Tools()
{
    var frm = new ToolFrm();
    frm.FormClosed += Form_FormClosed;
    frm.Show();

    return true;
}

private static void Form_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Form)sender).FormClosed -= Form_FormClosed;

    MessageBox.Show("Form was closed");
}
```

Note that if you don't unsubscribe from the `FormClosed` event, then the subscribing object will keep alive a reference to the form until the subscribing object is garbage collected.

To prevent that behaviour, you can unsubscribe from the event in the handler, as I have done with the line:

```
((Form)sender).FormClosed -= Form_FormClosed;
```

Comment: i want after frm.Show() code execution stop and when frm closed continue code execution

Comment: .Show() method cannot halt execution. Its a fire and forget method. Subscribing to FormClosed is a good idea.

Comment: "Note that if you don't unsubscribe from the FormClosed event, then the subscribing object will keep alive a reference to the form until the subscribing object is garbage collected." Sure, but as the form has already been closed, odds are that it's not going to be kept around for long at all.  The odds of someone holding onto a reference to that closed form is...slim.  There's no good reason to unsubscribe here at all.  In the very unlikely event someone is holding onto the closed form, that's almost certainly the bug, not this code.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to run code when the form is re-opened. The showdialog is actually a option you want and need to use.

```
    private bool Tools()
    {
        this.Hide();
        using (Form frm = new ToolFrm())
            frm.ShowDialog();
        DoSomethingYouWant(); //For example return true/false;
        this.Show();
    }
```

In the method `DoSomethingYouWant()` you can do anything you want to do.
The form will be hidden while the user untill the ToolFrm is closed.

If you want to run of example a new `FormLoad()` event, you can subscribe to it.
By replaceing the `DoSomethingYouWant()` with `FormName_Load(this, e);`

In the loading event you could do :

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Tools){
           Messagebox.Show("true")
        }
        if(!Tools{
           Messagebox.Show("false")
        }
    }
```